# Wildcard searches w/MySQL

Tags: mysql, search, wildcard

I've a situation where my wildcard search is not really working how I **thought** it should...
This is the MySQL query I am running and it will return only whole words...

eg.  If I enter "phone" as a search word it will return all rows with "phone" in it but not rows with "phones" (note the added 's')

```
mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM posts WHERE permalink = '$permalink' AND LOWER(raw_text) LIKE '%$str%' " );
```

How can I get it to return all variations of the search word? Obviously I know this could run into problems as it could return all sorts of matches if the user enters a common run of letters, I thought I could make this part of the advanced search option.

**ADENDUM**
I have narrowed it down to not a problem with the wildcard but with what I'm doing with the returned data... It is in my Regex that I am throwing at the data.

```
$pattern= "/(?:[\w\"',.-]+\s*){0,5}[\"',.-]?\S*".$str."(\s|[,.!?])(\s*[A-Za-z0-9.,-]+){0,5}/";

preg_match_all($pattern, $row["raw_text"], $matches);
```

The regex is not finding the string in the raw data that I am returning so it is throwing me a null.  A new problem, I'm not that familiar with regex so I will havbe to fugure this one out as well... Maybe I'll be throwing up a new question soon!

Thanks,
M

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but it may explain some weird behavior you'll see with it.  [Use a prepared query with mysqli_prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).  The code, as is, has "SQL injection vulnerability" written all over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something else is going on.  The `%` part of the query seems correct.  And this seems to be confirmation:

```
select 'phones' LIKE '%phone%';
+-------------------------+
| 'phones' LIKE '%phone%' |
+-------------------------+
|                       1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

By the way, I really hope you are doing a rigorous sanitation on `$str` (and `$permalink` too if it is from user input).  You should only allow alphanumerics and a small number of other safe characters (spaces, probably) and you should be running it through `mysql_real_escape_string()` before using it in `mysql_query()`.  Better yet, have a look at `PDO`.

Anyway, back to troubleshooting this:  One thing to try might be to have the program log the string your sending to `mysql_query()`. Basically, change the call to mysql_query() to a call to `error_log()` or `echo()` or something like that. Then copy and paste the resulting query into MySQL command-line tool or PHPmyAdmin or whatever. When that query doesn't work the way you expect, at least you can look at it and tweak it to figure out what's up. And who knows, maybe it will be super obvious once you see the query spelled out.

Comment: I agree... I can't seem to wrap my head around it though... I know that in my test data I have records that contain words and variations of words like "gun" and "guns", etc. But when I do the search for "gun" it will only return the records that contain "gun" and not the ones with "guns"... Hmm...

As far as sanitation, the permalink is generated by a function I created that strips all unfriendly characters and creates a friendly permalink.  As far as searches go, so far it is just taking the raw input but I will eventually clean up the search string and only allow certain characters.

Comment: One thing to try might be to have the program log the string your sending to `mysql_query()`.  Basically, change the call to `mysql_query()` to a call to `error_log()` or `echo()` or something like that.  Then copy and paste the resulting query into MySQL command-line tool or PHPmyAdmin or whatever.  When that query doesn't work the way you expect, at least you can look at it and tweak it to figure out what's up.  And who knows, maybe it will be super obvious once you see the query spelled out.

Comment: It was exactly what In thought in my addendum... The query was returning the data correctly, it was how I was manipulating the data afterwords with my regex... I fixed it now with a proper regex and it now works beautifully!  Thanks for the answers though!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a trailing space in your `$str` variable, which would explain what you're seeing: Your `LIKE` criterion would be `'%phone %'`, which matches `"... phone ..."`, but not `"... phones ..."`.

Try trimming your value first.

Comment: It was exactly what In thought in my addendum... The query was returning the data correctly, it was how I was manipulating the data afterwords with my regex... I fixed it now with a proper regex and it now works beautifully!  Thanks for the answers though!